# What do you call the people one interacts with?

Tags: vocabulary

Can I use "surroundings" reffering to people I communicate and interact with?
e.g. All my surrounding know I am a good person.
If not, what words can be used instead?

Comment: No, you can't - _my surroundings_ means the building or environment I am in.

Comment: Dmytro, there is not enough information to answer your question.  Doctors, police, family members, clerks, clergy, teachers, and pedestrians are all *people you interact with*.  We generally call that group *people you might interact with on a day-to-day basis.*  Can you narrow your request?

Comment: Note that it's **referring**, not **reffering**.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is ***associates***.

> All my associates know I am a good person.

This can refer to people you personally associate with, as well as in business.

Alternatively, you might need the word '*peers*', which specifically means those who belong to a similar societal group as yourself, such as those of a similar age at school, or university - people to whom you might normally compare yourself. Of course, your peers don't necessarily have to know you well, but you could say "among my peers, I am considered a good person", which would mean that you stand out as good within your societal group.

Comment: Your "associates" or "peer group" wouldn't normally include *family members* (and the former wouldn't usually include *close friends*, either). But to my mind, your "**social circle**" includes *everyone* you interact with on a reasonably regular basis.

Comment: **Social** might seem a good word, but according to [Edward Hall](https://bcmj.org/blog/social-distancing-origins-and-effects#:~:text=In%201963%20when%20Edward%20Hall,human%20closeness%20a%20big%20problem.), a cultural anthropologist, who coined the term proxemics to define studies about social distancing in everyday life, there are four main zones of space between individuals:...

Comment: ... Intimate distance (less than half a metre), such as in giving or receiving a hug.
Personal distance (about 1 metre), usually reserved for family or good friends.
Social distance (2 to 3 metres), when meeting strangers.
Public distance (more than 5 metres), such as in public presentations.

Comment: How do you know he's looking for *associates*?  Is the guy taking his order at McDonald's an *associate*?  I think not.  Not enough information has been provided. You're just taking a stab in the dark.

Comment: @EllieK Something called 'context'. Someone that serves you in McDonalds doesn't know if you're a "good person" or not.

Answer (score -1):

You could say **the people I know** or **the people around me**, which covers all possible angles. If you want something shorter, it's going to be more specific to types of people, as either **family**, **friends**, **coworkers**, or more vague collections like **peer groups** or **associates**.